# Extract method to already existing interface with ReSharper

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I'm adding a new method to a class that implements an interface, and I like to use the "Extract Interface" refactoring and just add the method to the interface. But it doesn't seem like ReSharper supports adding a method signature to an already existing interface.

It feels like I'm missing something, I'm sure it can be done somehow. Maybe I should add the method signature to the interface first, but this is the way I'm working sometimes. Am I missing some shortcut, feature or using ReSharper wrong?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+R to access the refactoring menu then choose **Pull Members Up...**

You can choose the interface that you want to add the declarations to and also select each method that you want to add to the interface.

Gotta love Resharper! ;-)

Comment: ARgh! I didn't even try that option because I thought it had to do with inherited base classes only. I could bet Extract Interface was the right choice... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Yep, I had exactly the same experience, Extract Interface seems the most intuitive option but hey, at least we've got a way to achieve the desired result :-)

Comment: I don't see it is working or existing in new ReSharper version

Comment: It's still working... but cannot detect existing interface and put new methods inside it.

Comment: @RJN Make sure the class you are in already implements the interface.